# How create a custom row in JasperReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have one query from my databse like that:

```
select name, age from Person
```

I did the report already, but...
How can I show one table like this? : [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XK1Kja5Hg4FwZutRcyuY?p=preview)

The idea that I can show all persons with age > 30 with row in other color and the age < 30 in white color.

How can I custom a row in JasperReports? Is it possible?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Is it possible?` - Yes. You need to apply *conditional style*

Comment: @AlexK Thanks, I was looking wrong :( ... I have solved my question.

Comment: @alex-k I have this, <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{grade}<'3']]></conditionExpression> I am comparing one String, yes I know but the bd returns me for instance: 3, 4, A, R. They are grades, when I did this in TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.3.1 It works fine!. But when I put my report to compilation in java, the <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{grade}<'3']]></conditionExpression> doesn´t work bcz The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) String, char. How can I handle this in JasperReport?? Any idea?

Comment: You should cast String to Number (Integer, for example). [How to convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585779/876298). The expression will be like this: `<conditionExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf($F{grade}) < 3]]></conditionExp‌​ression>`. In case you have not only numbers you can use some Java code, for example like at this post: [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1102891/876298). The expression will be like this: `NumberUtils.isNumber($F{grade}) ? Integer.valueOf($F{grade}) < 3 : false`

Comment: @alex-k Thanks for your explanation I get it. But where can I import my function that validate if my `NumberUtils.isNumber($F{grade})` inside my .jrxml ? of course I know that is from here [NumberUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html) but I was searching for how import a class inside report but the options in internet don't work for my case. I tried to put the dependency inside my pom.xml, bcz my proj is a maven proj, but this doesn't works still. I appreciate your answer!.

Comment: Yes, inside *jrxml*. You should use import like this: `<jasperReport ...><import value="org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils"/>`. [NumberUtils.isNumber(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber(java.lang.String)). You should also add *jar* at classpath

Comment: @alex-k perfect!! My app works. I just had to change Integer to `Double.valueOf($F{grade}) < 3` because the db also was returning doubles. Thank you so much for your help. Greetings.

Comment: You are welcome )